# Gremlin python filter by gte or lte

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I am trying to find a vertex that has a property called last_time_stamp which is between the range of last_time_stamp and last_timestamp - 1hour. The query below seems to work in AWS Neptune but fails in the Gremlin Python script.

I believe its failing because the word 'is' is reserved in python. Is there another way to write the query to achieve the desired results? Thanks in advance

Works in AWS Neptune:

```
g.V().has('private_ip_address', '10.2.55.24').values('last_time_stamp').is(gte('2018-05-01T13:06:52')).is(lte('2018-05-02T08:05:52'))
```

Gremlin-Python function:

```
#Need to handle public and internal on prem ips
def add_edge(label, account, interfaceid, srcaddr, dstaddr, srcport, dstport, protocol, packets, txbytes, starttime, endtime, action, logstatus):

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(starttime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
last_hour_date_time = datetime_object - timedelta(hours = 1)
endtime = last_hour_date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
print(endtime)

v1 = g.V().has('private_ip_address', srcaddr).values('last_time_stamp').is(g(endtime)).is(lte(starttime)).toList()

v2 = g.V().has('private_ip_address', dstaddr).values('last_time_stamp').is(gte(endtime)).is(lte(starttime)).toList()

print('v1:', v1)
print('v2:', v2)
```

another example I tried was this:

```
   v1 = g.V().has('private_ip_address', srcaddr).has('last_time_stamp', P.gte(endtime)._and(lte(starttime))).toList()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a workaround for `is()`. In Gremlin Python, steps that conflict with Python reserved words are just suffixed with an underscore. You would thus use `is_()`.

Comment: this fixed the initial problem.the second issue will be addressed separately. thanks.